# Django choices tutorial

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Can someone explain me what the function at the end of the coices example in the Django tutorial is for?

Thanks!

```
from django.db import model

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, default=FRESHMAN)

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upper class is a term used mostly in U.S based colleges to collectively denote Juniors and Seniors ( i.e the 3rd and 4th year students in a college with usually 4 year degrees, [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student#:%7E:text=Upperclassman%20to%20refer%20collectively%20to%20Juniors%20and%20Seniors)), this clears why such function was needed in the first place.

---

The function will return `True` or `False` if the value of `<instance-of-class-student>.year_in_school` is equal to `JR` or `SR`

If the syntax used in the body of the function is unclear, here are some examples of membership operators: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm